# Twitter API with Next.js

Tags: twitter, next.js, real-time

I am using [Twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) in Next.js. So when user passes authorization from  my app, he sends and api request to Next.js (access_token, access_secret) then i start Twitter streaming, to  fetch tweets in real time. Everything works fine, but when i Deploy to Vercel, api call  works, also i am  returning stream object with response to be  sure that streaming object is initialized, but in deployed  version it still doesnt work,  but in localhost or with ngrok  works  perfectly.

Comment: You need to provide the errors. Better when shown in combination with the code. You can open the browser console and look through the logs there.

Comment: the case is that i have no errors, it seems that everything works but i guess streaming subscription is being ignored in production  . the  problem is related to Vercel deployment, streaming api is not working  there but in local  host  it does.

Comment: It should throw an error if a core functionality is not working. If it is not showing an error. The error was handled in the code and the log messages were suppressed. Whatever the case is we cannot help you if you don't provide any code nor errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is showing no error, after long investigation i found that Twitter Api can not work properly because of client and server timestamps. So in vercel i couldn't change  server's timestamp, moved server to heroku it  works perfectly.